# xelatex select local math font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, siunitx, mathspec

The problem I am facing is that I am typesetting with `MinionPro-Regular.otf` as the main font and `MinionPro-Cn.otf` for the captions. However I have to declare only one math font for the whole document, thus math symbols and little `siunitx` things are not condensed.

Unfortunately `\setmathsfont` from `mathspec` does work only once in the preamble. Is there a way to change math font as you change the text font with `fontspec`? I don't need to typeset big formulas in captions only some numbers which are typeset using `siunitx`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
z\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}

\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt.otf}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,NoCommon},Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[BoldFont=MinionPro-Bold.otf,
               ItalicFont=MinionPro-It.otf,
               BoldItalicFont=MinionPro-BoldIt.otf,
               Color=black]{MinionPro-Regular.otf}         
               
\newfontfamily\captionfont[ItalicFont=MinionPro-MediumCnIt.otf]{%
                           MinionPro-Regular.otf}

\newcommand*{\mathtext}{\SI{2.3}{\micro\metre} %
2.3\,μm $x=2.3\,\mu m$}

\begin{document}\noindent
{\normalfont\itshape\mathtext} \\
{\captionfont\itshape\mathtext}\\

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

If you look carefully the `\mu` symbol in `siunitx`  in the second line is chosen from `\normalfont` not `\captionfont`. Also although I am using Mnsymbol the symbols are still from Computer Modern.

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`?

Comment: @egreg, yes it is there. MWE added now.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a variable font for the 'unit' part of quantities, and that is a text mode font, I think you are best off using text mode with `siunitx`

```
\sisetup{unit-mode = text}
```

This will then use whatever the current text font is for units, so the math font will have no impact. (Untested as I don't have the appropriate fonts.)