# Temporarily changing the math font in certain environments

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontspec, mathspec

A follow-up question to my earlier post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231478/selecting-font-features-for-tabular-data). In my document, I want to typeset the tables in a different font from the main text. I've managed to make that work for regular input. However, I occasionally need to use math in the tables. At that point, the font switches back to the regular font for the main text. I've tried things with the `mathspec` package, but cannot make it work. How can I change the math font temporarily for tables?

See the example below. I am not very strictly bound to `fontspec`/`mathspec`/`xetex` solutions, but since the rest of my setup depends quite a bit on it, I would prefer not to have to change that too much, or add many more other packages.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathsf[Numbers={Lining, Monospaced}]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
   \sffamily\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Lining}}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{A test}
This is a font test.

test, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, $1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9,\mathsf{9}$.

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{.25\linewidth}{lcc}
    &   Test & $a=b$    \\
a   &   1, 5 & $\mathsf{9}$     \\
b   &   2, 7 & $5$  \\
c   &   3, 9 & $3$  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(I saw [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/xelatex-select-local-math-font), which is related but does not quite give a solution to my problem.)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of a question asked a few minutes ago? You probably want to switch math versions having set up versions for each font set: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231911/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing that out! Cannot comment there, so I'll do it here: `\newmathversion{}` doesn't work (for me), but `\DeclareMathVersion{}` does. I've managed to make it work; I'll answer my own question below.

Comment: ah it would have helped id I'd got the right command name, will fix thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle who pointed me to the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231873/using-mathspec-setmathfont-with-newenvironment/231911#231911), and the example given [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-09/msg00181.html), I've managed to solve my problem. See below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\DeclareMathVersion{table}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers={Lining, Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont[math-style=TeX, version=normal]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright, bold-style=upright, version=table]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
   \sffamily\addfontfeature{Numbers={Monospaced, Lining}}%
   \mathversion{table}
}


\begin{document}
\section{A test with formulas: $\mathbfup{a+b=c}$}
This is a font test.
\section{A test with formulas: $a+b=c$}

test, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, $5+4=9$, $a+b=c$.

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{.25\linewidth}{lcc}
    &   Test & $a=b$    \\
a   &   1, 5 & $9$      \\
b   &   2, 7 & $5$  \\
c   &   3, 9 & $3$  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```